# Does the dependency "test" scope apply to the "integration-test" phase in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, integration-testing

When I build a project with Maven, dependencies with scope `test` seems to be out of scope during the `integration-test` phase. Is this by design, or is there anything I can do to have dependencies with scope `test` to be included during the `integration-test` phase?

[One answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244088/355232) suggests that test dependencies are in scope during the integration-test phase, but the answer is just a statement with no references. However, this does not appear to be how Maven works for me.

When I change a given dependency's scope from `test` to `compile`, the given dependency is (as expected) available during the `integration-tes`t phase.

Should the `test` scope apply to the `integration-test` phase, or will I have to set dependency scope to `compile` in order for them to be available during the `integration-test` phase?

This is the relevant part of the `POM` file. What I'm doing is that I attempt to start an instance of a MockServer during the integration test phase. However, it fails as the `com.company.msd` dependency not is included.

```
<dependencies>                      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.msd</groupId>
        <artifactId>MockServerDemo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>         
</dependencies>

[...]

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <serverPort>1080</serverPort>
    <proxyPort>1081</proxyPort>
    <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel
    <initializationClass>com.company.msd.server.DefaultExpectationInitializer</initializationClass>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
      <execution>
      <id>post-integration-test</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>stop</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note! If I add the dependency as a plugin dependency, it works. However, I'm still curious if Maven by design not includes test scoped dependencies in the `integration-test` phase.

Comment: Please a post a POM that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Tunaki question updated with relevant sections of the POM

Comment: In your POM, there are 2 bound phases -  `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test`. These two obviously are not `integration-test`, so it is clear that maven does not use `test` scope for both of them. 

Nevertheless, I've never seen phase-scope mapping in maven documentation. I've done some tests, and came to conclusion - maven uses only `compile` scope for `pre-integration-test` phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `maven-failsafe-plugin`'s `integration-test` mojo documentaion ([link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html)) and source code ([link](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-failsafe-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/failsafe/IntegrationTestMojo.java#L48)) it does require resolution of dependencies in `test` scope. In other words, it's not the phase that determines which dependency scope is used but the actually employed mojo.

In your case `mockserver-maven-plugin`'s `start` mojo does indeed only require resolution of dependencies in `compile+runtime` scope ([link](https://github.com/jamesdbloom/mockserver/blob/master/mockserver-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/mockserver/maven/MockServerStartMojo.java#L14)), whereas `stop` mojo requires the default `runtime` resolution scope ([link](https://github.com/jamesdbloom/mockserver/blob/master/mockserver-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/mockserver/maven/MockServerStopMojo.java)). See `requiresDependencyResolution` descriptor in Maven Mojo API documentation ([link](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations)) for further details.

If you get similar problems in the future, I suggest that you print out `effective pom` to understand how Maven interprets your configuration, or otherwise run Maven with `-X` flag so that you can see the actual class path for each mojo. Maven documentation may be ambiguous at times, but this way you can at least be sure how Maven works in practice.