# Maven - turn off warnings for specific pom

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a dependency that sometimes cannot be resolved (don't get to it... it is ok)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.g.g</groupId>
<artifactId>art123</artifactId> 
<version>1</version>
<type>rar</type>  
<scope>system</scope
    <systemPath>some location</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

when I clean install the entire project I get warning for this dependency (when it cannot be resolved).
Is there any way to turn off this warning? I tried to add

```
<optional>true</oprional>
```

to the dependency but still got the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have misunderstood how [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#How_do_optional_dependencies_work) work.

To solve your problem, I suggest that you create two [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) with different dependencies (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/167284/303598).

Answer (score 0):

You should never use system-scoped dependencies. Put this dependency into a repository manager and change your dependency to a usual dependency. I recommend really to use a repository manager (alphabetical order: [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/), [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php), [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)).