# Force maven to fail if two dependencies are included at the same time

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with the following structure:

```
parent
 > core
 > module-1 (with dependencies: A, B)
 > module-2 (with dependencies: X, Y)
 > project
```

`module-1` and `module-2` provide the same functionality (data access) in different environments.
Module `project` depends on `core`, and either `module-1` or `module-2`.

**Problem**: If I make `project` dependent on both `module-1` and `module-2`, there are a lot of unnecessary transitive dependencies (e.g. I don't need X or Y when deploying to enviroment #1, because only `module-1` is used there).

I would like to fail the build as early as possible if both `module-1` and `module-2` are specified as dependencies of `project`.

I wrote a test that looks for each module, and fails if both are found, but I think there should be an easier / more direct way to do that that.

Comment: (If there is a way, I've never heard of if ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use different profiles for your different environments. For a more extensive answer take a look at [Different dependencies for different build profiles in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven)

Comment: I think that I was trying to re-invent profiles (well... actually I cannot *enforce* the exclusion of unnecessary modules through  profiles, but that is not important since I can define a profile for each set of dependencies). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very odd case. The following may, or may not work, but I think it's a worthy idea, if you're willing to knock up some code, if you have to:

- Take `module-1` and `module-2` out into separate projects instead of having them as `<modules/>`.
- Check out the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) and [enforcer rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/). You will probably have to write your own rule.
- Add module-1 and module-2 as 'optional` dependencies.

Alternatively, you can clone `project` into two separate projects, remove all the code to another module and add that new module as dependency of `project-1` and `project-2`. Frankly, this is more of a code structuring and refactoring issue, than it is an actual Maven problem.

(And, in theory, Stephen C is right).

Comment: Thank you. I will consider the enforcer plugin for other assertions. As for this problem, I think it is overkill, since all I wanted was to be sure that I was building with a single set of dependencies. 

BTW, if the "modules" were separate projects I think I could enforce a rule through banned dependencies (`exclude module-*, include module-${module}`), but that doesn't work if the modules belong to the same project.