# Maven same dependency on different scopes

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven (3) project with multiple submodules. One on of them, I want it to explicitly depend on a dependency, without depending on its transitive dependencies. To do this, I'm using the folloing:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>*</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This works as itended. During runtime, the transitive dependencies of "foo" will already be in the classpath, so everything goes well.

However, I need "foo"'s transitive dependencies for test. I tried to also declare a dependency of "foo" with scope test, but it seems that it conflicts with the one that excludes everything. It either works as expected in tests but fails in runtime, or vice-versa.

Do you known if something like this is possible with maven?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible, you need to declare 2 different maven profiles holding your dependencies.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

[Different dependencies for different build profiles in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Maven's `<scope>import</scope>` dependencies. Create a `<profile/>` for testing and define a dependency to a `pom` which contains these test dependencies you're interested in. (This might require some re-working of your `pom.xml`-s, but would be a good approach).

Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) for more details.