# Update pom to use released versions

Tags: maven

Trying to find a way to update a pom to use latest versions of a RELEASED dependency instead of SNAPSHOT.

We have a assembly project that assembles an image to be deployed that during development uses SNAPSHOT dependencies.

But now I want to update the dependencies to use the latest released dependencies. Tried using versions:use-latest-releases but it only affects already released versions in the pom.

Any ideas?

EDIT (can not for security reasons post the pom but here's an example)

```
<project>
    ....
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>c-d-f</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>g-h-i</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

Given that component a-b-c and g-h-i has been released with version 1.0.1 and 1.1.6 I want to replace their versions in this pom with these version numbers. Basically remove any snapshot dependencies in the pom.

EDIT
I should add that is to be an automated process with minimal human interaction. For some reason I can only get versions:update-properties to work if versions are already in release state. If I have a snapshot version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and want to update it to 0.0.1 it doesn't happen and I have verified the release exists. Same thing with versions:use-latest-relese, and versions:use-releases does nothing at all.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? But I do not undertand well what happens? What you want is to change in your pom.xml a dependency for Snapshot to release? If it is that, why can not do it manually?

Comment: Is maybe `versions:use-releases` what you want?
Description: Replaces any -SNAPSHOT versions with the corresponding release version (if it has been released).

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html

Comment: @jne if you find here a helping answer, you can mark is "accepted"...

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches here:

1. You can create **multiple profiles** in your maven pom. Best way is to create a profile of "snapshot" and one for "release". Described here: [Different dependencies for different build profiles in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven)
2. You can use **maven pom properties** to define variables for your dependency versions. See here: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-user-defined

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven properties in your pom.xml, such as:

```
<properties>
    <c-d-f.version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</c-d-f.version>
    <g-h-i.version>1.1.6-SNAPSHOT</g-h-i.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>c-d-f</artifactId>
            <version>${c-d-f.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>g-h-i</artifactId>
            <version>${g-h-i.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        ...
</dependencies>
```

and when you want to change the versions, you can use maven-versions-plugin, with the following command, such as:

versions:update-properties -Dproperties=[${release_version}] -DincludeProperties={c-d-f.version}

EDIT:

Note that if you wanna use SNAPSHOTS, you need to add -DallowSnapshots. [Read here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html) for more options. And yes, the version needs to exist in the repo, otherwise it will fail. BTW did you use brackets, such as -Dproperties=[0.0.1]? after you read the link I sent you, you will see that this commmand's input is a **range**, so you must use brackets in order to specify a unique version.

Comment: This is exactly the thing I am looking for, but for some reason it always takes latest snapshot version. I tried even being explicit with allowSnapshots=false, but there is no way changing snapshot to release. Any ideas why? Is there a bug or something?

Comment: I think that if you wanna change from snapshots to release, the best approach is to use maven-release-plugin.

Comment: Does maven-release-plugin work on properties section?

Comment: yes, it knows to update therelevant props. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/