# How to run unit tests against several versions of a dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gradle, spock

I'm writing a java library `foo` which has a dependency on `bar:1.1+`.
But library `bar` has changed quite a bit over the time, and I'd like to ensure my library is compatible with every version of `bar` (`1.1` ... `1.10`).

So I'd like (during CI) to run each of my unit tests with a classpath including `bar:1.X`, with every version available of `bar`.

I'm using gradle and junit/spock but I'm open to solutions with variations.

Right I can duplicate by gradle test tasks, but that's pretty cumbersome, and the tests results may be difficult to aggregate.
Ideally I'd define right next to my test which versions of bar it should run with, e.g.:

```
@RunWith("com.acme:bar:1.1..1.10")
public class MyTest { ... }
```

But I find no tool/runner for that.

Comment: Well, with Maven you could simply define multiple profiles and start the tests with these profiles accordingly (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven ). I guess gradle has similar possibilities.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the tests you want to run here are actually integration tests, not unit tests. For unit tests, it would be usual to mock out the dependency on the bar library.

Comment: @unigeek not saying you're wrong, but it may depend what library `bar` is, let's say it's guava, no sane man will mock all its uses ^^

Comment: Perhaps you can somehow generate dependency configurations in Gradle for which each configuration has one version of the dependency. And then run the test task against those configurations. I'm sorry I'm not a Groovy expert to hint you on the code.

Comment: Do you use a build tool? Which one? Maven, Gradle?
What CI system are you using? Jenkins? GitHub Acrions?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Maven and not sure how its going fit with CI but may help you get started.

One option may be to use the [**Maven Archetype**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) `<-` More Info

Using the `mvn archetype:generate`, you can generate project with the version you need dynamically

```
mvn archetype:generate                                  
  -DarchetypeGroupId=<archetype-groupId>                
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=<archetype-artifactId>          
  -DarchetypeVersion=<archetype-version>                
  -DgroupId=<my.groupid>                                
  -DartifactId=<my-artifactId>
  -Dversion=<custom-version>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with maven archetypes, but AFAICT this will only help me generate one project per dependency version, which I'd like to avoid and keep a single project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now, there is at least three ways to do this.

- Use multiple classloaders
- Leverage [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html) to run a sample project
- Configure the CI to sed dependencies files (pom.xml, build.gradle.kts, etc.)

### Use multiple classloaders

I came accross this issue some years ago, and created a JUnit5 extension which does just that.
Concretely it will reload the test class with a dedicated classpath, built from the current Maven descriptor, using Maven to download what's missing.
Testing something against multiple versions of a same dependency will look like:

```
@CompatibilityTestWithClasspath(dependencies = {
  "com.acme:bar:[1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.10]"
})
void sample() {
  // test what you want
}
```

Here is the source of the extension: https://github.com/fridujo/classpath-junit-extension

### Leverage maven-invoker-plugin to run a sample project

You can use `maven-invoker-plugin` with multiple executions to run tests in the same project with different variables.
In the configuration of the plugin, you will have as many executions as versions you want to test against, each one specifying the property values to replace (with the `filterProperties` tag)
Here is an example of a project using this mechanism: https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock

### Configure the CI to sed dependencies files

Whether you use Jenkins, GitHub actions or any other CI tool or service, you will be able to have a job using `sed` to change versions in the project dependencies files, and re-run tests, in a loop or a *matrix* to test against multiple versions.