# Maven, exclude dependency with condition

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have two dependencies:

```
<dependency>A</dependency>
<dependency>B</dependency>
```

And variously I want to build A+B and A only.

So I should use some properties, but I'm not sure:

```
mvn clean package -Dcondition=X
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different dependencies for different build profiles in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven)

Comment: Why is this needed ? This sounds wrong?

Comment: I am surprised that Maven even allows this; it goes against the grain of reproducible builds. Given an artifact, how does one know which profile was activated thus producing a different build/dependency graph? Just because you can do it, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Would you consider having two separate dependent projects?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is combination of profiles and skip options for plugin section.

[Different dependencies for different build profiles in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven) - was usefull also.