# IntelliJ Spring Boot Run Configuration does not take test scope of maven dependendy into account

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Following scenario:

- spring boot 2.0.4 application
- maven 3
- IntelliJ 2018.1

I have a spring boot application that has a "local" profile and should use an in-memory hsql database.

**I have declared `hsqldb` as dependency with scope test, as I do not need it in production.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I know that when I manually create a classic Java Runner class, bootstrapping my spring boot application under my `src/test` directory, the dependency will get recognized and everything works fine.

But when I run my spring boot application locally via a Run Configuration/ Dashboard from IntelliJ it will not work.

So when I start the spring boot application, I will get the expected ClassNotFoundException.

Is there any way to let my spring boot application start in IntelliJ even with this test scoped dependency?

**UPDATE**

Defining the hsqldb dependency as scope runtime allowed to start from inside IntelliJ, but the hsqldb.jar got packaged in the final war file too....

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: When running spring boot the test dependencies will never be used. You could try building with a specific maven profile in development: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles-in-maven

Comment: I dont use maven to start the application, but internally from IntelliJ as stated in my question.

Comment: scope it as Runtime dependency, and prevent it from being packaged, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html

Comment: @DarrenForsythe `runtime` allowed me to start the application in IntelliJ but the hsqldb.jar still gets packaged into the final war file ...

Comment: Shouldn't be using intelliJ to create the jar, don't beliebe IntelliJ has the ability to delegate to mvn yet. Should not be there if you build it with maven

Comment: I build the war file via `mvn clean install` so it is maven, but the exclude mechanism does not work for the resulting .war file...