# Maven pom.xml argument that will install different dependencies depending on the value

Tags: java, maven, build

I would like to have a property/argument on Maven that will install a different dependency depending on the argument.

That is, when a user specifies `-DgpuCuda=True`, the dependency on the pom.xml will change accordingly.

So `mvn -gpuCuda=True install` will install DL4J-GPU instead of DL4J-CPU.

If -gpuCuda=True is specified, then this will be installed:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-10.1</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```

If -gpuCuda=False, this will be installed:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this possible? What would a workaround be?
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different dependencies for different build profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles). As for how to call it then, simply go for `-P<otherProfile>,gpuCuda` where `gpuCuda` is optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add something like

```xml
 <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>gpu</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>gpuCuda</name>
          <value>True</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-10.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>cpu</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>gpuCuda</name>
          <value>False</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles
```

Then you activate/deactivate the profiles by the command line properties you stated, like `mvn -DgpuCuda=True install`.

Comment: Thank you! Did this the trick! Is there a way to set DgpuCuda=False as default if user doesnt define anything

Comment: You can change the value from `False` to `!True`.