# Maven how to change dependancy version according to platform configuration (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, windows, maven, java-8

I'm trying to build a **JavaFX software application** for **windows platforms including windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10.**

I'm using **Maven** as a dependancy manager to build the project.

In my application, i make use of **MySQL Driver** for JDBC connectivity. However, when targeting **old OS such as XP**, i'm obliged to use **old drivers** because **nowdays versions of MySQL** are **impossible to start on XP.**

I need my project to get **built** with **MySQL 5.1.6 Driver for Windows XP** platform, and **MySQL 5.7 Driver for the rest of platforms.**

I'm aware that i can do that by building the project 2 times and proving 2 .jar files and then 2 different .exe files, but is there any other **elegant** way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different dependencies for different build profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, but still as said Karim, have to compile 2 times, the dependancy isn't picked according to the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around it because Java is precompiled, you gonna need to make an exe file  Windows XP and an exe for the rest of platforms, even if you use profiles (which I highly recommend to do in this case). You gonna have to make a profile for windows XP and a profile for the rest of the platforms and you going to compile it twice.

Comment: That's it (y) thanks (y)